# IHttpFilter implementation causes access violation for HttpClient::GetStringAsync call

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I'm in the process of factoring out OAuth authentication into an [IHttpFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.filters.ihttpfilter) for use with an [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpclient). I'm using the following code for testing, expecting that it would simply forward all requests to the [HttpBaseProtocolFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.filters.httpbaseprotocolfilter):

```cpp
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Web.Http.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Web.Http.Filters.h>

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Web::Http;
using namespace Windows::Web::Http::Filters;

struct TestHttpFilter : implements<TestHttpFilter, IHttpFilter>
{
    TestHttpFilter(IHttpFilter inner_filter) : inner_filter_{ inner_filter } {}
    IAsyncOperationWithProgress<HttpResponseMessage, HttpProgress> SendRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage const& request) const
    {
        auto const result{ co_await inner_filter_.SendRequestAsync(request) };
        co_return result;
    }
private:
    IHttpFilter inner_filter_{ nullptr };
};

int main()
{
    init_apartment();

    IHttpFilter const base_filter{ HttpBaseProtocolFilter{} };
    IHttpFilter const test_filter{ TestHttpFilter{ base_filter } };
    HttpClient const http_client{ test_filter };

    auto const result{ http_client.GetStringAsync({ L"http://aka.ms/cppwinrt" }).get() };

    printf("Response: %ls!\n", result.c_str());
}
```

The filter chain is properly created, and passed into the `HttpClient` c'tor. When issuing the `GetStringAsync` call, the code crashes inside `TestHttpFilter::SendRequestAsync` with the following error:

> ```cpp
> Exception thrown at <address> in <app>.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.
> ```

This looks to be a NULL pointer being dereferenced in the `put_abi` call inside the SDK header file *<Windows.Web.Http.Filters.h>* (namespaces omitted for brevity):

```cpp
template <typename D> IAsyncOperationWithProgress<HttpResponseMessage, HttpProgress> consume_Windows_Web_Http_Filters_IHttpFilter<D>::SendRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage const& request) const
{
    IAsyncOperationWithProgress<HttpResponseMessage, HttpProgress> operation{ nullptr };
    check_hresult(WINRT_SHIM(IHttpFilter)->SendRequestAsync(get_abi(request), put_abi(operation)));
    return operation;
}
```

I don't understand, where I went wrong with this. I hope to get to the core of it with answers to the following questions:

- Is there anything wrong with the `TestHttpFilter` implementation?
- Can HTTP filters be used with convenience implementations of the `HttpClient` (e.g. `GetStringAsync`), or are we required to go through the `SendRequestAsync` interface when using filters?
- Highly unlikely, but could this be an issue with the generated SDK headers, choosing an inappropriate c'tor for the local `operation` object?

I can reproduce the issue using the official Windows SDK version 10.0.17134.0.

Comment: You need to use the make<T>() function template to ensure that your implementation (e.g. TestHttpFilter) is heap allocated. The make function template will return the projected type.

Comment: @KennyKerr: That fixed it, thank you! I'm still not entirely sure, why, though. Presumably, the allocation store (heap vs. stack) is just a side-effect of using the `make<>()` template, and not part of the actual fix. Object lifetimes in the sample code are sufficient after all. I guess it's the fact, that `make<>()` returns the projected type from an implementation type, that is being consumed by a WinRT type (`HttpClient` in this case). Can you clarify that for me, in case you don't find the time to drop an answer yourself, so I can wrap this Q&A up?

Comment: The implementation must be allocated on the heap. It's more nuanced than that (as you've guessed) but that's the simple and safe way to get a correct implementation without any trickery. I talk about that here https://youtu.be/nOFNc2uTmGs?t=1h3m29s and briefly here https://kennykerr.ca/2016/11/09/cppwinrt-working-with-implementations/. The various helper functions are also starting to be documented here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/winrt I plan to make it a little harder to get this this wrong ideally at compile time but I want to be careful not to limit your options.

Comment: @KennyKerr: That was helpful, thanks. For a brief moment in history I was positive to have grasped the relationship between implementation types and projected types. Only to find myself wondering, why the Core Application template calls `CoreApplication::Run(App())`. With what I've learned I would have expected to see `CoreApplication::Run(make<App>())` instead. At any rate, I compiled an answer to this question in the hope, that it is at least approximately correct. Feedback would be much appreciated, though.

Comment: Those samples are incorrect. :) They happen to work due to a lifetime coincidence but they really should be using make<App>() as well. The reason those samples are written that way is because I wrote them a long time ago before it was called C++/WinRT. The earliest version of the projection attempted to make the implementation class appear to be stack allocated as well but it was not very efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/) projection comes with a bit of type duality<sup>1</sup>: There are [implementation types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/author-apis) that provide the implementation of a runtime class, as well as [projected types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/consume-apis) that contain the scaffolding required by the Windows Runtime, and act as a proxy to the implementation type.

This distinction becomes important when you author a runtime class that is to be consumed by a Windows Runtime API. The code in question implements a type, but fails to construct the corresponding projected type. The error is in the following lines of code:

```cpp
IHttpFilter const test_filter{ TestHttpFilter{ base_filter } };
HttpClient const http_client{ test_filter };
```

The first line constructs an instance of the *implementation type*. The second line passes it into the `HttpClient` c'tor, which expects a *projected type*<sup>2</sup>. The fix is to construct the projected type for `TestHttpFilter` instead, which can be conveniently done using the [make](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/make) function template:

```cpp
IHttpFilter const test_filter{ make<TestHttpFilter>(base_filter) };
HttpClient const http_client{ test_filter };
```

General advice:

- Always make sure you understand, what type you are working with. Establish naming conventions to discriminate between implementation types and projected types.
- When crossing the ABI it is (usually) required to pass a projected type. You typically cross the ABI when calling a Windows Runtime API, or when you return a value from an implementation type.
- Whatever you do, don't let this fail at runtime. Chances are that there is at most a single person in this universe that can help you out when you get there.

---

<sup>1</sup> *See [What do the projected type and the implementation type mean?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/faq#what-do-the-projected-type-and-the-implementation-type-mean)*

<sup>2</sup> *Ideally, this should fail to compile, although I wouldn't know how to implement that without (unduly) limiting the versatility of a general purpose library.*